# Changing data from json using a form

Tags: php, json, postgresql, forms, geojson

I'm trying to select and store data into a geojson format from the database using a form , but when i try to add the data it says "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data",and i want to be able to change the data whenever somone enters other values in the form fields.the connection works ok, and the json file works when im not using the form and enter some values from tabel. 
here is the code:

Form:

```
<div style='background:#171E24; text-align:center'>
    <form class="form" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="number" id="number"  placeholder="number"  >
        <input type="text" name="startDate" id="sDate"  placeholder="start date"  >
        <input type="text" name="endDate" id="eDate" placeholder="end date">
        <input type="submit" name="search" id="search" value="search">
    </form>
    </div>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
   if(isset$_POST['search']){
    include('testcon.php');
    $number='number';

    $startD=$_POST['startDate'];
    $endD=$_POST['endDate'];

    $startData=strtotime($startD.'00:00:00');
    $pgsqlstartdata=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$startData);

    $endData=strtotime($endD.'23:59:59');
    $pgsqlenddata=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$endData);

    $query=pg_query($connect,"SELECT number, condition, date, lat, long "
        . "FROM schema.table "
        . "WHERE number = '$number' AND "
        . "data BETWEEN '$pgsqlstartdata' and ' $pgsqlenddata' ");



          $geojson = array(
          'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
          'features'  => array()
           );
           # Loop through rows to build feature arrays
           while($row = pg_fetch_array($query)) {
          $feature = array(

         'type' => 'Feature', 
         'geometry' => array(
          'type' => 'Point',
        # Pass Longitude and Latitude Columns here
        'coordinates' => array($row['lat'], $row['long'])
    ),
         # Pass other attribute columns here
          'properties' => array(
          'number' => $row['number'],
        'condition' => $row['condition'],

        )
    );
       # Add feature arrays to feature collection array
          array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);

      header('Content-type: application/json');
      echo json_encode($geojson, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
      $conn = NULL;
      ?>
     }
```

`

I want to put the data on a leaflet map, but i dont really understand how to change the data from geojson file .